# Creating a database in Xcode

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I want to create a searchable database in Xcode - for example, of different trees. The database would consist of the tree name, two images, price, and a short description. What is the best and most efficient way of creating such a database?

I am aware of: Core Data, SQLite3, and Parse. I am leaning towards SQLite3 but have not found a good place to learn how to implement this. Any suggestions?

Comment: It depends on how you plan to use the data. There is no single right answer.

Comment: Apologies. I want it to be searchable by the user using a search bar.

Comment: Core Data is not a database.

Comment: Search around for an ORM with an interface you like the look of, I can't give an opinion because it will just be my bias and not a fair and open opinion.  But look at the examples, and think about how far you may want to take this in the future with performance requirements before picking one.  Because you will be text searching, you may have to look quite hard and do your research.

Comment: Have you discovered yet that there are free Objective-C front ends to sqlite that make it very easy to use?

Comment: Please bear with me as I'm new to this. Please elaborate on "Objective-C front ends."

Comment: Here is a good tutorial: http://www.apptite.be/tutorial_ios_sqlite.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you are new to Objective-C and I doubt this will evolve into something need direct SQL I would suggest using CoreData. Although it is not technically a data base it is an object graph, it is built for exactly what you are wanting to do. Apple was even nice enough to build wrappers for everything you want to do.

1. CoreData to store your tree name, two images, price, and a short description.
2. `NSFetchedResultsController` for grabbing it.
3. `UISearchBarController` for letting the user search.

You would want to use Parse if you wanted to save your data to a server. If your doing everything locally I wouldn't worry about Parse. CoreData is what you want.